# Need help to find FireMonkey equivalent of the VCL TpaintBox.Canvas.Handle in the context of building graph

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

**Preambule:**
I'm working with Black Magic Design (BMD) Decklink input card to acquire HD video signal. They provide C++ Sample with their SDK. I've successfully translated the c++ sample into Delphi (VCL). I've also isolated the API call in a TDecklink witch I want it to be available to the Delphi community. It work very well in VCL (I can provide the TDecklnk with a demo app to use it if requested).

Now I need to acquire the signal in a FMX form (but not crosscompile to other platform than Windows). I've tried to modify the TDecklink to be usable in FMX without success.

**Core Question:**
In my VCL version, I pass a TPaintBox refference to my TDecklink. The TPaintBox is used by the GraphBuilder as area to display the live video.

Here is some line of code I use in the VCL version to assign the TPaintBox to the GraphBuilder:

```
      pWnd := WindowFromDC(FpboxPreview.Canvas.Handle);   //WindowFromDC  retreive HWND from HDC
      hr:= pIVMRWindowlessCtrl.SetVideoClippingWindow(pWnd);   // set the bounds of the video to the preview window
      if hr = S_OK then
      begin
        previewRect.Left   := FpboxPreview.Left;
        previewRect.Right  := FpboxPreview.Width;
        previewRect.Top    := FpboxPreview.Top;
        previewRect.Bottom := FpboxPreview.Height;
        hr:= pIVMRWindowlessCtrl.SetVideoPosition(nil, @previewRect);   // show the whole of the source frame in the whole of the client area of the control
        hr:= pIVMRWindowlessCtrl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMR_ARMODE_LETTER_BOX); // maintain the aspect ratio of the video
        hr:= pIVMRWindowlessCtrl.SetBorderColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));    // set the colour of the letter or pillar boxed area
```

Where PWnd is a HWND

In FMX, what is the best component and parameter to use to provide what the GraphBuilder expect to receive ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VCL, `TPaintBox` is a `TGraphicControl` descendant that draws onto the `HDC` of its `Parent` control's `HWND`.  When the `Parent` control receives a `WM_PAINT` message, it draws itself onto the provided `HDC` as needed, and then temporarily gives that same `HDC` to each child `TGraphicControl` when drawing them, clipping the `HDC` to each child's coordinates and rectangle accordingly.  If you try to draw onto a `TGraphicControl.Canvas` from outside of its `Parent` control's `WM_PAINT` handler (which you should never do), `TCanvas` will temporarily grab the `Parent` control's `HDC` using the Win32 API `GetDC()` function.

Thus, this statement:

```
pWnd := WindowFromDC(FpboxPreview.Canvas.Handle);
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
pWnd := FpboxPreview.Parent.Handle;
```

So, you are actually putting your video on the window of the `TPaintBox.Parent` control, not on the `TPaintBox` itself.  If you want the video associated with its own control, consider using `TPanel` instead, as it is a `TWinControl` descendant with its own `HWND`.

FireMonkey, on the other hand, has no concept of `TGraphicControl` and `TWinControl`.  Every control is a `TControl` descendant with an overridden `Paint()` method to handle any custom drawing onto a `TCanvas` that is provided by either the parent `TForm` or the caller of the `TControl.PaintTo()` method.  FireMonkey does not even create an `HWND` for each control.  Only the parent `TForm` has its own `HWND` (so it can interact with the OS).  Child controls are drawn directly onto that window, adjusting the drawing coordinates and clipping rectangle accordingly as they go along (under the hood, FireMonkey uses DirectX (Windows) or OpenGL (other platforms) for all of its drawing).

So, if you really need an `HWND` for your video class to display on, you will have to either:

1. use the `HWND` of a `TForm`, which you can get by either passing its `Handle` property to the 
   [`FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform) function (or the [`FMX.Platform.Win.FmxHandleToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FmxHandleToHWND) function on older FireMonkey versions):

   ```
   uses
     ..., FMX.Platform.Win;

   pWnd := WindowHandleToPlatform(Form1.Handle);
   ```

   Or passing the `TForm` itself to the [`FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function:

   ```
   uses
     ..., FMX.Platform.Win;

   pWnd := FormToHWND(Form1);
   ```
2. use the Win32 API directly to create your own `HWND` as needed and then embed it inside the `HWND` of a `TForm`.

Otherwise, you will have to re-think your video UI in FireMonkey.  For instance, assuming the video class can provide you with images of the video frames, you can draw them onto the `TPaintBox.Canvas` from within the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event (which is how `TPaintBox` is meant to be used in the first place, in both VCL and FireMonkey).  Or maybe derive your own custom `TControl` that pulls images from the video class in its own overridden `Paint()` method.  I don't know what your GraphBuilder class is capable of, but BMD provides an SDK for controlling video recording/playback hardware and accessing video data (see [this PDF](http://www.goodshooter.com/ahigh/Blackmagic%20Decklink%20SDK.pdf)).

Comment: Hi Remy, this is good explanation. I found useful to know that the painting is in reality putted in the parent window of the TPaintBox. This drive me to modify my VCL version of the TDecklink, now instead of passing a refference of a TPaintBox, I pass a HWND plus the coord. of a TRect where I want the video to be painted. By this way, in the VCL version, I can use a TForm, a TPanel or a TPaintBox (as the user want)and it work. I've tried the same TDecklink but in FMX and by passing the TForm handle (FormToHWND(frmMain)), it compile but I never see any video. Suite on the second comment.

Comment: I think you awsered corectly to the first question, it's why I will checkmark it. I can qualify me a s an expert in video equipment but i'm a part time developper. Graph and filter of direct show is not trivial for me. I've translated the C++ sample of the BMD Decklink SDK in Delphi VCL with success but i've translated it like someone can translate a text to a foreign language with a dictionary but without knowing the languare subtleties. By reading and reading again and again the sample, it become more simple for me, but the behaviour of VCL and FMX seen totally different. Continued

Comment: It's why I think I need help on how to build the graph to be working on FMX instead of trying to translate it one to one. I have put he projects (VCL and FMX) on SourceForge, maybe someone will have the time to give me a logic to be used successfully with FMX. Thank a lot. For those who want to take a look, the SourceForge link is [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdecklink)

Comment: I cannot answer why the video does not appear in FMX. Maybe the FMX hwnd is not compatible with Decklink in some way, or maybe you provided the wrong coordinates for the painting.

Comment: What is most fustrating, it's the fact that FMX is marketed as most powerfull for 3d and multimedia, and, in fact the transition capabilities is cool. But, when connecting to professional equipment, it's a nightmare !

Comment: Gets worse: all painting is synchronised with the main thread, so unless you want your video to freeze each time the main thread stalls (e.g. click the form's title bar), I'd stay away from FMX

Comment: I'm agree with you Mike, I advance a lot, now a can vizualise the incoming video in the FMX form but it is painted on over the other components (not on the backgrond like in VCL form). And when going mouseover of a component, the video image flash. It's no my decision to be in FMX but the rest of the software of near finished and it use FMX feature extensivelly. I must find another logic in the DirectShow filter creation. it must be like the TCaptureDeviceManager who work weel with by example a web cam..